# Is it normal for the occasional drywall screw to eventually poke through their covering spackle?

Tags: drywall

Our home is about 6.5 years old, is a new construction (from a national company), and we've been the only owner.

I'm starting to notice spots around the house where the drywall screw has pushed out its covering spackle, breaking the texture.  While it's easy enough to fix (but annoying), is this normal behaviour?  Were the studs not completely dry, and this is an indication that there's been some expansion/contraction?  The depth of the screws looks correct.

We live in Colorado, so it's pretty dry all year round, and we do not have a whole-house humidifier.

Comment: Screws or nails? Big difference. "Nail pops" have long been an issue with drywall, depending on many factors. "Screw pops"? Not so much, with the exception of screws that didn't hit studs but were left in instead of being removed. Pictures might help.

Comment: Occasional yes, where the name nail pops come from.

Comment: Screws.  Almost positive it's code here.  And to be clear, the screw has not come out (or unscrewed), the depth in the sheetrock looks fine.

As for pics, I'll need to find another one as I've already spackled over the most recent two that spawned my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s probably normal. Lumber is not dry enough nowadays.  So essentially the lumber shrinks around the screw.  When it shrinks, it essentially shrinks from the center of attachment, thus leaving a gap.

The second cause can be poor construction practice, like getting insulation between drywall and stud, or a twisted stud, or something like trying to fit a 3.5” pipe and insulation in a 2x4 wall(my personal favorite).

To fix, put screws in above and below and tighten the original a bit, testing by pushing on the screw area and observing if there is movement.

I’ve seen houses with glued drywall still have issues with screw pops. It’s best to have the house dried in for a bit before drywall happens.